# SVG file upload in TCA: sanitize or validate

Tags: svg, typo3

The TYPO3 backend user wants to upload SVG files for the footer.
This is realized by TCA File upload currently, limited to file type: svg.
We had already errors in the uploaded SVGs, and inline PNGs.

Now we need to validate or sanitize the SVG, to avoid code errors by SVG.

- svg-sanitizer is available in TYPO3 core:  (https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.5.x/Important-94492-IntroduceSVGSanitizer.html) Is it possible to connect this with TCA File Upload?
- other idea: hook into the TCA File Upload and write the sanitizer there?
- Validator would be OK as well: if validation fails, upload is stopped and user gets error message.

Any other ideas are welcome - the requirement is: the Editor wants to edit footer SVGs, Developer wants only valid SVGs.

Comment: Which TYPO3 version is used and how does the "TCA file upload" exactly look like? Can you please update the question accordingly? Thx

Answer (score 0):

If the SVG is added via backend, it is sanitized automatically

Comment: And what if not? Is there a way of testing it: 
- What SVG errors should be removed for sure? (to see if it is doing at least something)
- if it is not working at all, I think some server settings are to be done. Is there a command line test option?

Comment: there is an update wizard which could be used as kind of test